# AngularJS - bootstrap popover, how to use correctly "popover-is-open" in a ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I have a ng-repeat that generates a list of items in a table, 
each item has a button in its row, and that buttons opens a popover (to edit the object).

It is important that I don't use: `click-outside` property of the bootstrap popover, because this popover must be closed only with the button inside it.

so in the html code where the popover is declared on the `<div>` that has the ng-repeat we have this code:

```
         <div class="popoverX" popover-class="popoverCustom" 
    popover-append-to-body="true" popover-placement="bottom-left"
         popover-is-open="vm.isEditPopoverOpen" 
uib-popover-template="'Views/xxx/popTemplate.htm'">
```

in the controller this is defined:

```
 isEditPopoverOpen: boolean;
```

and the close function that we have inside the popover, to close it, is:

```
   closePopover() {
      this.loading = false;
      this.isEditPopoverOpen= false;      
    }
```

so everything works great when we got only a single item returned in the ng-repeat, but ofc that is not the case, so currently, when you click on the row `div` that opens the popover, every popover for every line gets opened.

I get why this is happening, because I'm using the same boolean,
but what s the solution then?

I need this structure to stay, so the popover must be closed only with a button,
and I would like to AVOID to add a new property on the objects in the array that is looping in the ng-repeat, like a : `isOpened: boolean`, and then use that for the open/close.

If there are any other solution I would be happy to hear them!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really don't want to assign new properties on your objects, you could keep a separate array of opened/closed popovers like this;

```
vm.openedPopovers = [];
```

and in your markup you can access `$index` in the repeater like so;

```
<div class="popoverX" popover-class="popoverCustom" 
     popover-append-to-body="true" popover-placement="bottom-left"
     popover-is-open="vm.openedPopovers[$index]" 
     uib-popover-template="'Views/xxx/popTemplate.htm'">
```